# find out if keys from one dictionary are present in list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Hello I am looking to do find out this:

Assume I have this.

```py
a = {"kid": 34,
     "adult": 20,
     "very young": 6,
     "old": 10,
     "teenager": 70,
     "baby": 12,
     "very old": 8}

b = [{"name": "Tom", "age": 10, "tag": "kid"},
     {"name": "Mark", "age": 5, "tag": "baby"},
     {"name": "Pam", "age": 33, "tag": "adult"},
     {"name": "Mario", "age": 15, "tag": "teenager"},
     {"name": "Lara", "age": 86, "tag": "old"}]
```

I would like to know how I could possibly get something like this:
if the key in `a` is present in `b`, then divide key value by 2

So I would get something like this :

```py
17
10
5
35
6
```

As you can see when the key from `a` is not in `b` it will just skip the position and do nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `any()`:

```
for k, v in a.items():
    if any(d["tag"] == k for d in b):
        print(v // 2)
```

Prints:

```
17
10
5
35
6
```